# top of the button in my header cuts off when using padding: 20px;

Tags: html, css

[image: Top of button cuts off]

I'm building a button into my header so people can click on it and it takes them to a modal to fill out contact information. It cuts off the button like shown in the picture above.

My HTML:

```
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="site-header__logo">
            <div class="icon site-header__logo__graphic icon--clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="site-header__menu-icon">
            <div class="site-header__menu-icon__middle"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="site-header__menu-content">
            <div class="site-header__btn-container">
                <a href="#" class="site-header__btn">Request A Demo</a>
            </div>
            <nav class="primary-nav primary-nav__pull-right">
                <ul>
                    .....
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

My CSS

```
.site-header {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgb(207, 206, 206, .5);

    &__btn {
        background-color: $mainOrange;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;        
    }

    &__btn-container {
        float: right;

    }
}
```

When I remove the `padding`, the header flushes with the top. When I change the `padding` to `margin` it pushes the header down from the top.

Any ideas on how to make the button whole?

Comment: You are using some sort of preprocessor for your CSS. Please add a tag for it.

Comment: I think we are missing some of the relevant css. However, from what you have here, I think the issue is that your floating element parent needs a relative position, a min-height and you need to clear your floats.